# What were common outcomes for white 17 year olds charged with attempted rape around 1982?

Tags: united-states, law, crime, sexuality

When United States Supreme Court nominee Kavanaugh was publicly accused of a 1982 attempted rape at age 17, his defenders noted that the accuser Dr. Blasey Ford had not obtained redress by pressing charges at the time. Maryland had [two relevant charges](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/public-safety/amid-the-ford-kavanaugh-exchanges-have-the-local-police-been-asked-to-investigate/2018/09/27/7787d8c0-c297-11e8-a1f0-a4051b6ad114_story.html) then on the books: attempted rape (a misdemeanor) and assault with attempt to rape (a felony). This episode motivates the following question about events of the early 1980s in the United States.

What were common outcomes when white 17 year olds *did* face a charge like this around 1982?

Doing keyword searches to link some starter precedents, I only found tangentially related cases, nothing seeming similar enough to mention. Someone that has access to a faceted legal search engine may more readily perceive the trends in juvenile attempted rape cases. By all means broaden the search in terms of location, charges, and year, but I'm only interested in U.S. cases where the defendant was both white and a juvenile. I left defendants' families' capital and influence off the list of criteria because getting that data seems impractical.

Comment: would there be a different charge / outcome if the perpetrator was black?

Comment: @drewbenn - I'd be very much surprised if the actual % for that wasn't far lower in the 80's even than it is now. While I'm not a teen today, I was then and I know well what attitudes were like among teens at the time. I had both perpetrators and victims in the 80's confide incidents to me in that they clearly had no clue were actually rape. (and yes, they totally were)

Comment: @drewbenn Understood. There will be no data on cases that weren't reported, but a case doesn't have to go to trial to leave a paper trail. Dropped charges or plea bargains could have been common outcomes.

Comment: Weren't / aren't juvenile records sealed? That might make this difficult or impossible to answer.

Comment: @justCal Good point. Minor defendants' names are probably omitted from the case records.

Comment: With his mother being a judge I guess the odds of a conviction would be even less.

Comment: Speaking for the UK, there was an infamous case some 20+ years ago when a judge found a rape victim "partially responsible" because she was hitchhiking. There was also a fly on the wall documentary on a police force which showed untrained male officers treating a complainant/victim like a suspect. It caused such a furore when aired, it led eventually to the introduction of comfortable rape suites and specially trained officers. But rape victims are still accused of dressing provocatively, of "leading him on", etc.

Comment: I was a (white, middle class) teenage boy in the '60's. The *majority* of the young women I knew closely enough to talk about such things had been raped. None of them reported it, or apparently even imagined doing so.

Comment: Kavanaugh is innocent, get over it. This question is race baiting also as it implies white people were less likely to be charged with crimes simply because they were white. This is backdoor racism just like the nothing invented in Africa question asked recently.

Comment: @Daniel The question says nothing about Kavanaugh's actions. In framing it, I preferred to control for the possibility that race groups were treated differently, rather than assume as you do that they were treated the same.

Comment: @AaronBrick You preferred to use one extreme over the other. don't pretend otherwise.